# AWS Kinesis modified data

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-redshift, amazon-kinesis

I would need an advice on the AWS analytics architecture I would need to set up to achieve this:

I have a RDS database that gets its records modified often and is too big to be configured as a datasource to be graph by any tool like quicksight for example.

I thought Kinesis and redshift could be the solution: create a producer -> kinesis firehose -> s3 -> redshift. That does the trick actually when the flow is just a set of new records. But when I have incoming changes of a same record the COPY command executed by firehose to redshift is not convenient to manipulate old records.

My question is: what should I use in terms of AWS solution to analyse incoming updated data?

thanks

Comment: What type of update do you want to do? Like an upsert?

Comment: yeah that's the idea. But the question is more general maybe. Is redshift the right choise for dynamic records? is redshift appropriate. The use case is a large user account database that I would like to analyse. RDS is too slow when the data set is too large.